# How do I grab pieces of text from a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, text-parsing

If a user submits a string like:

> My living room plans #plans #livingroom @cbmeeks #design @moe @larry -this is cool!

I want to have the following arrays/strings:

```
text = "My living room plans"
tags = ['plans', 'livingroom', 'design']
people = ['cbmeeks', 'moe', 'larry']
description = "this is cool!"
```

Every string submitted will start with the `text` piece.  No `@`, `-`, etc. I don't have to worry about a user starting with a tag or person. The breakdown should look something like this, in any order except TEXT is always first.

```
TEXT [-description] [#tags] [@people]
```

**EDIT**
I can't seem to figure out how to grab them correctly.  For example:

```
a = "My living room plans #plans #livingroom @cbmeeks #design @moe @larry -this is cool!"

/#\w+/.match(a).to_a
#=> ["#plans"] -- only grabs first one
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've written so far?

Comment: `a.scan /..../` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will automatically remove the `#`, `@`, `-`, and will match in any order:

```
string = "My living room plans #plans #livingroom @cbmeeks #design @moe @larry -this is cool!"
text = string[/^(.*?)+(?=\s[@#-])/]
tags = string.scan /(?<=#)\w+/
people = string.scan /(?<=@)\w+/
description = string[/(?<=-)(.*?)+?(?=($|\s[@#]))/]
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you but this is friggin awesome and exactly what I was looking for.  My regex skills are pretty weak.  I'd like to give you another 100 points if you could explain HOW that works.  like what is the `(?<=-)` for?  I'm assuming the `-` in it is because description starts with a `-`.  Thanks

Comment: `?<=` is a look-behind. It means only match a word preceded by the indicated character, but don't include that actual character. So `(?<=-)` finds a string preceded by a dash (`-`), but doesn't include the dash.

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to avoid having to use strip and removing the trailing space with a regexp too, but my regexp skills aren't terribly advanced.

Comment: By the way, look-behinds only work in Ruby 1.9 and not in 1.8 or earlier.

Comment: +1000 for you.  I am using 1.9 and I confirmed it still works after I jumbled the string around.  **perfect**  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
input = "My living room plans #plans #livingroom @cbmeeks #design @moe @larry -this is cool!"
text = input.match('^(.*?)#')[1]
tags = input.scan(/#(.*?) /)
people = input.scan(/@(.*?) /)
description = input.match('-(.*?)$')[1]
```

Comment: This won't match in any order, and doesn't strip the symbols off the front.

Comment: Thanks.  This was almost perfect.  Much better than I could think up.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = 'My living room plans #plans #livingroom @cbmeeks #design @moe @larry -this is cool!'

text = str[/^([^#\@]+)/, 1].strip # => "My living room plans"
str.sub!(text, '') # => " #plans #livingroom @cbmeeks #design @moe @larry -this is cool!"

tags        = str.scan( /#([a-z0-9]+)/ ).flatten # => ["plans", "livingroom", "design"]
people      = str.scan( /@([a-z0-9]+)/ ).flatten # => ["cbmeeks", "moe", "larry"]
description = str.scan( /-(.+)/        ).flatten # => ["this is cool!"]
```